# How to track custom variables in emails so webhook can post data with custom variables?

Tags: email, web-applications, mailchimp, mandrill, webhooks

I'm trying to create an app where a user can create an issue and it will send an email to some other users notifying them that this issue has been created.

I want any of these users that received an email to be able to reply to the email and be able to capture the email and parse it to get the issue_id that was originally sent.

I'm currently trying to use [mandrill](http://mandrill.com/) to send and receive emails and when they receive them, they parse them and post the contents to my webhook.

What is the best way to send emails from my app with an issue_id (maybe in a header or something?) so that when someone replies to that email, the issue_id can be pulled from the data sent to my webhook so that I can update my database for that issue with the reply.

**EDIT**

A perfect example that I just thought of is how when you resopnd to a gihub email about an issue or a pull request, it automatically posts your email reply to the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What most web apps do is have the object specific ID as a part of the Reply-To address.

For example, Facebook uses addresses like:

```
g+<49-character string>@groups.facebook.com
```

as Reply-To for notifications about comments, while GitHub uses:

```
reply+i-<8-char>-<40-char string>-<7-char>@reply.github.com
```

Many email provides support `+<string>` concatenated to your address, like Gmail. If you have your own domain you'll likely be able to set up any pattern match you like. I haven't used Mandrill specifically.

Comment: Interesting...I was going down the route of trying to piece together the message-id header and in-reply-to headers in my app, but it's proving to be quite the challenge.